# how to input a file and use it to count the upper/lower-case letters, numbers, and punctuation?

Tags: c

My goal is simple.  To ask a user for a simple text file containing upper/lower case letters, digits and punctuation.  Then take the file, open it, and scan for each of the aforementioned elements keeping a count of each.  Lastly, output a total for each (i.e. total uppercase letters contained, total lowercase letters, total digits and total punctuation marks).

Unfortunately, my question is not so simple.  I am confused really at how exactly (i.e. at the concept of, and syntax for) the way C passes an input file to a function like fgetc and then tests it to increment counters.  My program crashes and I an running low on ideas why.  I guess my initial question then is, why does it crash?  My code is below;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    char Character = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int upper_case = 0;
    int lower_case = 0;
    int punctuation = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int entered_words = 0;
    char user_filename[100];
    char user_filecontent[100];



    printf("Enter the filename of the file containing text and/or digits:\n");
    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
    gets(user_filename);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (user_filename, "r");


    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
    }


    while((fp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {


            while((Character=fgetc(fp)) != '\n');
            {

                if (isalnum (Character))
                {
                    if (!entered_words)
                    {
                        entered_words = 1;
                        words++;
                    }
                }


                else
                {
                    if (entered_words)
                    {
                        entered_words = 0;
                    }
                }


                if (isupper(Character))
                {
                    upper_case++;
                }


                else if (islower(Character))
                {
                    lower_case++;
                }


                else if (isdigit(Character))
                {
                    digits++;
                }


                else if (ispunct(Character))
                {
                    punctuation++;
                }

            }

    fclose(fp);
    }

    printf("Total number of words is %d.\n", words);
    printf("Total number of digits are %d.\n", digits);
    printf("Total number of uppercase letters is %d.\n", upper_case);
    printf("Total number of lowercase letters is %d.\n", lower_case);
    printf("Total number of punctuation characters is %d.\n", punctuation);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    char Character = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int upper_case = 0;
    int lower_case = 0;
    int punctuation = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int entered_words = 0;
    char user_filename[100];
    char user_filecontent[100];



    printf("Enter the filename of the file containing text and/or digits:\n");
    printf("(hit the Enter key when done)\n");
    gets(user_filename);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (user_filename, "r");


    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading\n");
    }


    while((Character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {

                if (isalnum (Character))
                {
                    if (!entered_words)
                    {
                        entered_words = 1;
                        words++;
                    }
                }


                else
                {
                    if (entered_words)
                    {
                        entered_words = 0;
                    }
                }


                if (isupper(Character))
                {
                    upper_case++;
                }


                else if (islower(Character))
                {
                    lower_case++;
                }


                else if (isdigit(Character))
                {
                    digits++;
                }


                else if (ispunct(Character))
                {
                    punctuation++;
                }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("Total number of words is %d.\n", words);
    printf("Total number of digits are %d.\n", digits);
    printf("Total number of uppercase letters is %d.\n", upper_case);
    printf("Total number of lowercase letters is %d.\n", lower_case);
    printf("Total number of punctuation characters is %d.\n", punctuation);

return 0;
}
```

I removed the inner while loop and moved the fclose function call outside the loop.

Comment: Ugh!  it works now, thank you!  I was fixated on two loops thinking I needed that to continue reading the file until EOF was reached.  I hadn't thought of combining the two for one loop!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning to your `FILE *fp` the result of an `fgetc` in your while test:

```
while((fp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

This is probably the cause of your crash. `fp` is the handle to your file once you've called `fopen`, after that you only need to pass it to functions that take a `FILE *`, like `fgetc` and `fclose`.

Also you're calling `fgetc` twice: once in the `while` test, and then immediately following in another `while` test. You'll lose characters this way, even after you fix the `fp` problem. Why do you need the inner loop?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that thanks.  I've changed this statement to

Comment: but it still crashes with no debug info...I've been trying to get this to work all day now with no success :(

Comment: the problem with your change is that it still consumes a character, that you don't do anything with. you need to call `fgetc` once and only once for every character in the file. don't call it only to check `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

man fgetc tells

> fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an
>   unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

You must use an int variable to store this result

Comment: but how would I make fp an int variable in this case?  fp is the pointer to the opened file...

Comment: use an other variable as suggested by drjd