# Overwhelmed with how to accomplish program

Tags: c

You are to write a program that reads characters from the keyboard using the getch() function. 
All lower case letters will be converted to upper case and printed out to the
display using the putchar() function. All uppercase letters will be printed using putchar().
All individual digits will be accumulated and the sum will be printed at the end of the
program using printf(). 
You will write a function to return the upper case of the letter and
a second function which receives the current sum and the character digit. The convert
digit function will convert the character digit to a decimal value and accumulate the digit
to the sum returning the new sum. Only the letters will be printed out nothing else. 
The program will continue until the return is received at which time the sum of the digits will
be printed on the next line.
What was entered: a9 wF23’;/4i
What the line actually shows: aA9wWFiI
The sum of the digits is: 18

The skeleton of what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int uppercaseconversion (int c);


int digitconversion (int sum, int c);



  int main() 
{

    int c, upper;
    int sum = 0;


    printf("Please enter a character or characters ");

   while (c !='\n') {
    c = getch();

    // Check for a digit
    if isdigit(c)
    {
        digitconversion (sum, c);
        continue;
    }

    // If lowercase, convert to upper case




if (islower(c) )
    {
    c = uppercaseconversion (int c);
    }
    if (isupper(c)) 
    {
    putchar(c);
    }

    printf("The sum of the digits is %d\n", sum);   






    return 0;
}

int uppercaseconversion (int c);
{
    c = toupper(c);
    return c;
}

int digitconversion (int sum, int c);
{

        sum += c - '0';

    return sum;
}
```

Also after re reading the program description. I must output the char using putchar() and then print the sum. Since I am outputting using char and not a string I think I have to print out every loop or else the value is lost?

Then when enter is pressed or return the sum is finally printed.

I don't have to print what was actually entered. I think the professor added that as an example.

****Above code is what I have. Currently broke on 
line 57 1   F:\group2 assign\main.c [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

i am told It's because getch() is a non-standard function.

Comment: I would advise breaking it down into small steps.  First just make a program that accepts input and echoes it back.  Then add a little, like filtering out anything that isn't a letter or number.  Then add the extra uppercase letter for lowercase, etc.  Some hints:  Check for lowercase: `if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`  Check for digit" `if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')`  Integer from digit: `n = c - '0';`  There are also standard functions to test for these, you can see some of them in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11925291/920069

Comment: That is really simple. I did not realize I could check for greater or less than a letter. Interesting!

Comment: from a *character... not letter

Comment: You do not output the uppercase converted character as you should.  Convertly, you should not print the digits but you do.  Hint: use `isdigit` to check for digits and call `digitconversion` only for those, and add the missing `putchar` for the converted lowercase characters.  What does the assignment say about other characters? How do you handle them?

Comment: Another problem: you do not test for EOF.  This program will go into an infinite loop if you encounter `EOF` before a `'\n'`.  Try redirecting an empty file as standard input.

Comment: Why prompt "Please enter ..."?  Can you imagine how irritating it would be if `grep` started by prompting `please enter a regex to match`?  Imagine trying to do `cmd | grep foo | grep bar` if you had to filter out prompts!

Comment: Yea I am suppose to ignore the digits except for the sum. So I have to move the put char.

Comment: Strange question with continuous update. Actually is hard to understand what NeuromancerNoob want

Comment: Will how else will the user know what to do?

Comment: Guys I'm sorry that description up above is the literal assignment from the school. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ...

```
printf("Please enter a character or characters ");
while (c !='\n') {
    c = getch();

    // Check for a digit
    if isdigit(c){
        sum += c - '0';
        continue;
    }

    // If lowercase, convert to upper case
    if islower(c) c = toupper(c);
    if isupper(c) putchar(c);

}
```

EDIT:

Actually the `continue` isnt necessary because we are checking what we print ...

```
printf("Please enter a character or characters ");
while (c !='\n') {
    c = getch();

    // Check for a digit
    if isdigit(c) sum += c - '0';

    // If lowercase, convert to upper case
    if islower(c) c = toupper(c);
    if isupper(c) putchar(c);

}
```

Comment: Interesting dialect: C without parentheses.  Yet the logic is correct and much simpler.

Comment: This is only for the segment within the while loop. The rest should remain the same, although `int sum = 0;` should be initializes somewhere close to the beginning of the `main()` function ...

Comment: 28 8 F:\group2 assign\main.c [Error] expected '(' before 'isdigit'

Comment: @NeuromancerNoob: There is a little typo in the code, it's just missing some parentheses around the boolean-condition of the if-expressions.

Comment: @NeuromancerNoob  I dont have a C compiler. I used https://ideone.com/efApww Seemed to be OK there. I also had to change `getch()` to `getchar()`, but otherwise I didnt change anything. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: dev c++ and I cant use getchar it has to be getch :( I;m trying to do the convert in the functions.

Comment: https://ideone.com/LtW1pQ   ... There were a couple of tiny errors in your program. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `islower()` to determine if a char is lowercase; Use `isdigit()` to determine if a char is a digit; Use `toupper()` to convert a lowercase letter to uppercase.

If `c` is a digit char, then `c - '0'` will give you the number.(Look at the ASCII chart.)

Comment: Ok thank you that is very helpful. At what point does a program use ASCII?

Comment: @NeuromancerNoob ASCII is a base for almost all encodings. Your system is probably using a superset of it.